# Struts2: Textboxes of different sizes

Tags: html, css, textbox, struts2

I am creating a login page with the following input fields:

```
<td>
    <s:textfield  class="loginInput" name="username" label="Username" id="un1" size="20"/>
    <s:password class="loginInput" name="password" label="Password"  id="pw1" size="20"/>
</td>
```

However, when I compile and run the page, the two textboxes show up with different sizes. The Username textbox is slightly bigger than the password textbox.

I tried adding the size attribute to make them display the same length. I even tried adding a CSS element to have them display the same size, still nothing. Any suggestions?

Edit: I should add that this only happens in I.E. works perfectly fine in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which theme you are using? Since `size` is a valid parameter of struts2 text-field. i suggest you to do following steps:

Use simple theme:

```
   <td>
        <s:textfield theme="simple" cssClass="loginInput" name="username" 
         label="Username" id="un1" size="20"/>
        <s:password theme="simple" cssClass="loginInput" name="password"
        label="Password"  id="pw1" size="20"/>
    </td>
```

If you have not set up a theme, Struts 2 uses the `"xhtml"` theme by default. This means it will create additional HTML with `<td><tr>` for input elements out of the box

I hope this should work.

**FYI:** I tested your code in my local machine here is the screen shot and everything is working perfectly fine

[image]

Are you sure you are using your CSS and other things correctly??

Comment: I have tried that, but when i use the simple theme, my login page transforms from:

Username: [TEXTBOX]
Password: [TEXTBOX]

to:

[TEXTBOX][TEXTBOX]

Comment: What browser are you using? Because I only get this error in Internet Explorer. And yes, my CSS is working fine, I am using it in other places on the same page

Comment: @user1073616 i have checked in Mozilla,IE and chrome everywhere its working perfectly fine.you can show up your html code being generated may be some one familiar with HTML can point out the thing

Comment: Damn, must be interference from some other code. Thank you anyway. I wish I could vote you up for helping but I still cant vote...

Comment: @user1073616 The "simple" theme does not emit labels.

Comment: Is there a way to change the height of a textField. I see a width attribute but not height.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with IE. At least on IE 9 (Win 7), the problem can be observed using a simple static document with the markup

```
 <input><br><input type=password>
```

The boxes are of slightly different width, because the text font is different. You can fix this by setting the fonts to be the same, e.g. using the following CSS code:

```
 input { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Arial is the default font for text input boxes in IE, so this will just adjust the password field to use the same font.